# stop scanner when it reads the last word

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm not too experienced with scanners, but I wrote a method to read each word from a txt file and for each, add one to an int, but they int just keeps increasing. I would like it to stop when it reads the last words/adds the last one.

```
    public void drawnames(Graphics g) throws FileNotFoundException{
    int str = 0;
    String[] string = new String[800*600];
    int xpos = 100;
    int ypos = 100;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Particles/Names.txt")));
    while(s.hasNext()){
        string[str] = s.next();
        g.drawString(string[str] + str, xpos, ypos);
        str = str + 1;
        ypos = ypos + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `str` outside of `drawnames`? And what int keeps increasing?  I'm so confused

Comment: Yes, the int (*str* presumably) keeps increasing. Is that a problem? Where is **str** defined!?!?! And **string** for that matter!

Comment: okay, i added str and string, and yes, i would like str to stop increasing when it reaches the last line/word

Comment: So you are saying it NEVER stops increasing? You mean it gets stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: Close your scanner after the while loop with **s.close();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after your while loop add this:

```
s.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

s.HastNext()  will always return true as s never changes.

You could use hasNextline() instead perhaps.

Take a look at the docs here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29

Comment: I've tried changing that, but it still just keeps going up :L

Comment: No. **s** does change. s.next() forces s to change.